# Android: Multiple variables to reference a single view?

Tags: java, android

everyone.

I'm asking this here, because I just want to know how to reference a single view from multiple different instances, but I've been searching around, and no one seems to have asked this, let alone answered. It doesn't help that the wording confuses search engines and gives results to the exact opposite (referencing multiple views with one variable).

I'm new to Android development, and I wanted to do a simple application that uses TextureView to display something on screen. All I want to know is if variables assigned to views behave the same as any other kind of variable?

Say, in the case of an integer, you could do this:

```
int a = 1;
int b = a; // b now takes the value of a, therefore becomes 1.
```

However, when assigning a view to a TextureView in Android to a variable, and doing the following:

```
TextureView myTextureView1 = findViewById(R.id.Main_Texture_View);
TextureView myTextureView2 = myTextureView1;
```

Does this produce the same result? If not, what is the proper way of referencing the same view with another variable? Is what I'm asking even possible at all?

What I want to do is use multiple variables to do different work, like obtain different information from the view (for example, calling getBitmap() from another method, or something), but I don't want to render the view many times, as I'm aware TextureView is very resource-intensive. However, I'm aware that the resource "Main_Texture_View" is only defined once in the layout, so it shouldn't mean it will be rendered many times, am I right?

Comment: As far as I know, it will produce the same result.

Comment: Does that mean both variables will point to the same view?

Comment: yup they will point to the same view.

Comment: "Does this produce the same result?" -- yes. "What I want to do is use multiple variables to do different work" -- there is no need to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TextureView myTextureView1 = findViewById(R.id.Main_Texture_View);
TextureView myTextureView2 = myTextureView1;
```

Will produce the same results.  Same works for strings.

```
String a;
String b;
String c;

a = "1";
b = a;
c = a + b;
```